# Change password

Tags: lightning, change-password

I am trying to build a custom page with lightning components where the users of my community can change their own password. I want to do it with the site.changepassword method as described here:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm

I am actually not managing to make it working. What am I doing wrong?

This is my component

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  controller="B2B_Partners_Form_Controller">


<aura:attribute name="isManditory"              type="boolean"      default='false'     access="public" />
<aura:handler   name="init"                     value="{!this}"     action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
<aura:attribute name="labels"                   type="Object"       description="labels of the fields"/>
<aura:attribute name="stepnumber"               access="public"     type="integer"  description="number of step"/> 
<aura:attribute name="checked"                  access="public"     type="boolean"  description="checkbox input" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="highestNumber"            access="public"     type="integer"      description="highestNumber"/>
<aura:attribute name="password"                 type="String"       default="" />
<aura:attribute name="oldPassword"              type="String"       default="" />
<aura:attribute name="terms"                    type="boolean"      default="" />

<!-- set grid -->
<div class="slds-p-top--xx-large">
    <div class="slds-grid start_middle">

        <div class="slds-col slds-card slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-left--xx-large ">
            <div class="slds-p-right--xx-large ">
                <div class=" slds-p-top--large slds-p-bottom--medium slds-text-heading--large boldFont">{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_SetupPassword}</div><br/>

                <div class="slds-p-top--large ">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-has-divider--bottom  bookFont">
                        <lightning:input type="Password" label="Your current password" value="{!v.oldPassword}" aura:id="inputOldPasswordSecret" onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border widthPassword slds-show" name="inputPasswordSecret" />
                        <lightning:input value="{!v.oldPassword}" label="Your current password" aura:id="inputOldPasswordText" onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border input widthPassword slds-hide sfdc" name="inputPasswordText"  />
                        <div class="slds-align--right">
                            <div class="slds-clearfix">
                                <div class="slds-p-top--large slds-float--right">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="{!c.toggleOldPassword}" onmouseup="{!c.toggleOldPassword}">
                                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:preview" size="small" class=""/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-p-top--large ">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-has-divider--bottom bookFont">
                        <lightning:input type="password" label="{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_Choose_Password}" value="{!v.password}" aura:id="inputPasswordSecret" onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border widthPassword slds-show" name="inputPasswordSecret" />
                        <lightning:input value="{!v.password}" label="{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_Choose_Password}" aura:id="inputPasswordText" onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border input widthPassword slds-hide sfdc" name="inputPasswordText"  />
                        <div class="slds-align--right">
                            <div class="slds-clearfix">
                                <div class="slds-p-top--large slds-float--right">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="{!c.togglePassword}" onmouseup="{!c.togglePassword}">
                                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:preview" size="small" class=""/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" slds-m-top--large slds-text-align--right slds-p-bottom--medium">

                    <!-- go back button -->


                    <lightning:button label="Cancel" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.onClickCancel}" iconName="{!$Resource.B2B_Partners_goBack}" class="slds-m-horizontal--small buttonSize boldFontBlue">
                        <div class="slds-grid">
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <img class="goBack slds-m-right--x-small" src="{!$Resource.B2B_Partners_goBack}"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-m-right--medium previousColor">
                                <p>{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_Previous}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </lightning:button>

                    <!-- go to next button -->                      
                    <lightning:button label="Save changes" variant="brand"  onclick="{!c.onClickSave}"  class="sfdc_button slds-p-left--large slds-p-right--large borderButton mediumFont"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

This my controller:

```
    onClickSave: function(component, event, helper){
    helper.savePassword(component, event, helper);
}
```

This is my helper:

```
savePassword: function(component, event, helper){
    var password        = component.get ('v.password');
    var password2       = component.get ('v.password');
    var oldPassword     = component.get ('v.oldPassword');

    var action = component.get("c.changePassword");

    action.setParams({
        "password": password,
        "password2": password2,
        "oldPassword": oldPassword
    });

    action.setCallback(this,function(a){
        var state = a.getState();
        console.log('helper 3')
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            console.log('succes')
        } else if (state =="ERROR"){
            component.set('v.message', 'echt niet');

        }
     });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
```

This is my apex class:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String changePassword(String password, String password2, String oldPassword){

        return JSON.serialize(Site.changePassword(password, password2, oldPassword));

    }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error message while doing so?

Comment: The parameters transmission to the back-end controller seems to be done the right way. Could you please perform some System.debug in your back-end controller in order to be sure the parameters are received as they should ? Other than that, you may have noticed that this function returns a 'System.PageReference' on which they effectively redirect to change the password ? I'm not 100% sure so i can't post it as an answer but it might be this.